# GlassFish 2.1 : Which Java EE version?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-6

i am a beginner in Java EE development..

I am using **GlassFish server v2.1** with **JDK 1.6**, what is the highest version of **Java EE** that i can work on ?

and which of those two defines the Java EE version, GlassFish or JDK ? can you explain how does it work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Glassfish V2 is Java EE 5 compatible.
if you want Java EE 6 you will need glassfish V3 , and the current version is glassfish v4 for java EE7

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/v2.1-b60e.html) GlassFish 2.1 supports Java EE 5. Neither the version of the app server, nor the JDK tell which Java EE version is supported by the app server. A look up is needed.

Comment: is there any other way to work on a higher version of Java EE with Glassfish 2.1..

Comment: The container IS the JEE platform. Its not some program that services the Java Enterprise Edition, the server IS the implementation if the Java Enterprise Edition specification. So if you want a higher version, you need a newer Glassfish.